# Export and Import .xls(x) in C# - table error

Tags: c#, excel, import, export

I'm using these connection strings, depending on the extension of the file:

```
  public static string ExcelConnectionString(string filePath)
  {
                OleDbConnectionStringBuilder sbConnection = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
                String strExtendedProperties = String.Empty;
                sbConnection.DataSource = filePath;

            if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xls"))//for 97-03 Excel file
            {
                sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
                strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0";//HDR=ColumnHeader,IMEX=InterMixed
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xlsx"))  //for 2007 Excel file
            {
                sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
                strExtendedProperties = "Excel 12.0";
            }

            sbConnection.Add("Extended Properties", strExtendedProperties);

            return sbConnection.ToString();
    }
```

However, When I import the xls file without using the "save as: 2003 xls" or "save as: xlsx" option. (So when I save my downloaded file by <kbd>control + s</kbd> it won't work.) I end up with this error:

> *OleDbException was unhandled by usercode - External table is not in the expected format.*

How can I fix this? My system needs to work with <kbd>control + s</kbd> to save the file, instead of manually choosing one of the 2.

Problem could be the export I make*, because when I open the file by hand after export I see this window:

```
The file you are trying to open "yourfile.xls" in a different format than specified file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?
```

*The export file is a generated XML file saved as .xls.
Is there any way I can save this as .xls without warning? I really need the <kbd>control + s</kbd> to save the file.

Thanks in advance.

In short:
How can I save my created XML file as XLS without getting the error displayed above.
I do not want to use external libraries, only if it's really impossible to do this without them.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file? It might help to also post the code where you are using the connection string to open the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overwhelming evidence that the file is **not** actually a spreadsheet file that was saved in the native Excel format.  In other words, a *real* .xls or .xlsx file.

So you are doing battle with a crummy program that just picked the wrong file name, the program that converted the XML file.  A likely format choice for such a program is .csv, Comma Separated Values.  A format that Excel knows how to read.  The OleDb provider you use is however not quite that smart about it.  It needs to know the *real* format from the connection string.

You really do need to know what the file actually contains to know how to configure the connection string.  A starting point is to look at the actual content of the file.  Use a hex viewer.  If you can't make sense of it then post a screenshot.  Or use Notepad, my crystal ball predicts that you'll see perfectly readable text.

---

> It starts with: `<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>`

Update: the document is formatted as an XML file, I can repro the headings by saving a spreadsheet using the "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format.  The expected filename extension is `.xml`.  The OleDb provider cannot read the document as-is, conversion is required.  You can write a little console mode app to take care of it.  Project + Add Reference, COM tab, select "Microsoft Excel x.x Object Library".  Make the code resemble this:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args) {
        var app = new Excel.Application();
        try {
            if (args.Length != 2) throw new Exception("Usage: Convert inputfile outputfile");
            var book = app.Workbooks.OpenXML(args[0]);
            System.IO.File.Delete(args[1]);
            book.SaveAs(args[1], FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
            app.Quit();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            app.Quit();
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case: make sure you look at the *output file* of that converter, not the input file.

Comment: I've used CSV before indeed, but somehow it should be possible to update the file to be a "real" file right? Like "save As" does?

Comment: Converting from CSV to XLS requires using Excel.  Sure, that's possible, you can automate it with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.  Not actually necessary, your OleDb provider knows how to [read CSV as well](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/).  You just have to tell it about it.  So, what does the file actually contain?  Did you try opening it in Notepad?  What does it look like?

Comment: It starts with:"<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><DownloadComponents/>" AND saved als .xls displays black block with [NUL] and [ETX] or [DC4] in it, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Replace code for your 97-03 Excel file (".xls") to following

```
sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0";//HDR=ColumnHeader,IMEX=InterMixed
```

This connection string is used to use Office 2007 OLEDB driver (ACE 12.0) to connect to **older 97-2003 Excel workbooks.**